# Pass separate scope in each new Instance created in ES6

Tags: javascript, function, scope, ecmascript-6

I have written some code as below. Here I am creating new instances for the class 
`todos` and passing separate text each time to the constructor.

inside `setText` i am binding a click method to the element `test` so that it returns its the text associated with it on click of it.

Problem here is, the three components created by this method has separate texts displayed but on click of any element it displays the text as `'this is a todo component3'` which is the last text i passed into the constructor. I want it to be separate for each component. Please help.

```
class todos{
  constructor(text){
    this.istodo = false;
    this.text = text;
  }
  _changestatus(){
    this.istodo = !this.istodo;
  }
  setText(){
    this.getDiv  = document.getElementById('test');
    this.getDiv.innerHTML = this.getDiv.innerHTML+'\n'+this.text;
    this.getDiv.onclick = (event)=> {alert(this.text)}; //this is always coming as "this is a todo component3"
  }
}


let todo = new todos('this is a todo component');
todo.setText();
let todo1 = new todos('this is a todo component1');
todo1.setText();
let todo2 = new todos('this is a todo component2');
todo2.setText();
let todo3 = new todos('this is a todo component3');
todo3.setText();
```

Comment: You are using always `document.getElementById('test')`

Comment: yes right, thanks, i did not notice that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have only one container for all your texts and every next todo you add, overwrites `onclick` handler created by previous one. So this is the problem.

To solve it you need to make sure every todo creates its own container for the text. Below is one possible way to do it. Note, that I removed `document.getElementById('test')` from the `todos` class.

```js
    class todos {
      constructor(text) {
        this.istodo = false;
        this.text = text;
      }
      _changestatus() {
        this.istodo = !this.istodo;
      }
      setText() {
        this._node = document.createElement('div');
        this._node.appendChild(new Text(this.text));
        this._node.onclick = (event) => {
          alert(this.text)
        };
      }
      getNode() {
        return this._node;
      }
    }

    let container = document.getElementById('test');

    ['this is a todo component', 'this is a todo component #2', 'this is a todo component #3'].forEach(text => {
      let todo = new todos(text);
      todo.setText();
      container.appendChild(todo.getNode());
    });
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```